# Problem with custom 404 page

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, apache-2.2

Don't know if this question is appropriate here.

I created an Alias directed to the root folder of the website (right now running on localhost).  In the root folder, I have a custom 404 page, and I've added a .htaccess file in that folder with the "ErrorDocument 404 /404.html" line, but it still doesn't work.

I'm pretty new to this stuff (web servers), so I must be missing something obvious.  Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: what has the error_log of apache to say about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, just looked at the Apache Documentation, needed to add the ErrorDocument directive in the Alias.

Comment: Can you close the question then?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to more fully document the problem and answer as opposed to closing the question?  That way someone in the future might google "custom 404 page problem" and find the answer here.